# Cannot send ajax post request to Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, post

Here is my code.,

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.post("AjaxpostloginServlet.java",
                {
                 name:"kevin",
                 pass:"Duckburg"
             });
         });
});
```

**Java servlet**

```
package com.iappuniverse.ajaxpostlogin;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class AjaxpostloginServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
         public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws     IOException
           {

              String name=req.getParameter("name");

              System.out.println(name);

           }
    }
```

The name here in the servlet doesn't get printed in the console. Trying to send data to  the server using ajax `.post()`, but cannot make the servlet linked to the ajax `.post()` call run.

Comment: Try removing `.java` from your `post` method. Use `$.post("AjaxpostloginServlet")` instead of `$.post("AjaxpostloginServlet.java")`

Comment: Your ajax request must be send to the url that your servlet is mapped. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html

Comment: Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484556/how-to-ouput-text-to-java-console-from-servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `web.xml` to something like the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Application</display-name>
    <description>
        Description Example.
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>AjaxpostloginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

lets take it a step further and change your servlet post method

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws IOException {
       String name=req.getParameter("name");
       response.setContentType("text/plain");
       response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       response.getWriter().write(name);

}
```

finally change the url of the ajax call and use a callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.post("login",{
                 name:"kevin",
                 pass:"Duckburg"
             }).done(function( data ) {
                  alert( "name: " + data );
             })
         });
});
```

**Disclaimer:**
I haven't test it!